# Tab Bar Controllerで6項目以降のView Controllerのインスタンスを取得したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tab Bar Controllerに6項目以上の項目を追加した場合、4以降のView Controllerのインスタンスを得たいのですが、

```
self.childViewControllers[viewIndex]
```

で取得できるのは`viewIndex`が[0..3]の時のみで、4以降は「More」View Controllerが挿入されるため、moreNavigationControllerプロパティを使ってアクセスする必要があるようなのですが、具体的にどのように取得すればいいのか分かりません。どなたかご教授ください。
Objective-Cベースでの回答をいただけると助かります。

Comment: Objective-Cベースで回答をもらいたいのか、あるいはSwiftベースなのか、タグを追加することで、明確化していただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。
Objective-Cベースでご回答お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> self.childViewControllers[viewIndex]

`self`を`UITabBarController`のインスタンスとすると、

```
self.viewControllers[index];
```

で、全タブ（のView Controller）を取得できるようです。

`childViewControllers`は、`UIViewController`のプロパティ、`viewControllers`は、`UITabBarController`のプロパティです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
UIViewControllerのプロパティではなく、UITabBarControllerの方のプロパティで簡単に取得できたんですね。大変参考になりました。